# How to run Valgrind in parallel with our process so its performance doesn't decrease too much?

Tags: linux, multithreading, debugging, valgrind

I need to use Valgrind to detect any memory access violations made in a server application. The server creates many threads. I suspect that there is a racing condition that causes the server to crash every 1 hour or so. We used Valgrind to analyze its memory usage but the server process' speed decreased dramatically. The server's speed decreased so much that it was hardly usable and no racing conditions where probable.

Is there anyway to run Valgrind in parallel with our application so we don't lose that much performance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's worth noting that Valgrind, while supporting multi-threaded programs, will not actually run the program's threads in parallel if you have multiiple cores available. It also interleaves threads at a finer grain than the native OS scheduler. These 2 facts combined might make it so a program with race conditions or other concurrent anomalies will behave differently.

You may want to try [Helgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html), a tool primarily aimed at detecting correct locking discipline and [drd](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/drd-manual.html), a tool primarily aimed at detecting data races.

Answer (score 10):

You can't do that. Valgrind doesn't actually execute your code natively - instead it runs it inside a simulator. That's why it's so slow. So, there's no way to make it run faster, and still get the benefit of Valgrind.

Your best bet is to set the `ulimit` so that your program generates a core file when it crashes. Then you can try to work out what the problem was by examining the core.

Answer (score 1):

This is not directly answering your question, but if you suspect a synchronization error, have you tried using the Valgrind tool [**Helgrind**](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html)?

Comment: I wasn't aware of Helgrind before as I'm not a professional Valgrind user. I've just learned about it today. I suspect is that an object is getting deleted but another thread is trying to access it and that crashes the process. This is highly probable since the application has been coded very poorly. I'll try Helgrind and see what it can offer.

Answer (score 0):

Valgrind works by hooking into your malloc calls, so you can expect your program to run slower under valgrind. So, I would say that you could not run your program faster under valgrind *and* get the benefit of analysing memory errors.